# problematically create Virtual IPaddress java

Tags: java, virtual-ip-address

I am creating a simulation device and i need virtual IP address created on my server. I can create it manually via LocalAreaConneciton Properties dialog (in advanced tab). But i want to create it programatically via Java. Also I might need this IP address to be reachable from any server in that submet [ Currently it is ping ing when we create it manually] 
I did searched in google but could not get a free utility. There are few paid utility from adventnet etc. 
Please help me on this regard.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved this problem myself

```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("netsh", "interface", "ipv4",
                "add", "address","Local Area Connection 3","10.24.41.63","255.255.248.0");
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process process = pb.start();
```